# How to check if users bought in-app-purchases after "You've already purchased this Tap OK...."

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased gets called when users bought in-app purchases first time AND users tapped the OK button after "You've already purchased this.  Tap OK to download it again for free".

I want to set a mixpanel analytic endpoint ONLY when users buy in-app purchases first time.

Is there any way to differentiate this?

Comment: u get userid or udid whens first time purchase then send to server after second time check userid or udid

Comment: Thanks, so it' pain to check this then.  I hoped it can be done with some delegation methods.

Comment: I am trying to make the same differentiation, since I display a message to the user afterward saying "Thank you for your purchase.". I don't want to do this if they are not making a new purchase or they will be concerned. Did you figure out a simple way to make this differentiation?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I changed my message from "thank for your purchase" to "the app has been upgraded!" not to confuse users.